# how to add admob Interstitial ad to my webview app using android studio?

Tags: android, admob

I have already add an admob banner to my website app following the instructions from a youtube video , now I want to add an Interstitial ad , any advices ?

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mscs.lim.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4873432488084596/8921164178">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are 3 activities and the opening sequence is as follows:

> Activity_A --> Activity_B --> Activity_C.

Now you want to show interstitial Ad between Activity_B and Activity_C.
First loaded the Interstitial Ad in Activity_A and then call(or show) in Activity_C.
You can do above like this:

In Activity_A i.e. MainActivity add code like this:

```
public void showme(){

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed()
            {
                //reload interstitial
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
//                        .addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                        .build();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
```

Call this showme() in Activity_A inside OnCreate.

In Activity_C paste below code inside OnCreate:

```
Activity_A.showInterstitial();
```

My advice is to load Interstitial Ads in very first Activity (i.e. MainActivity) and then call it in any other activity.
The good thing about this method is that It doesn't violate any Admob or Adsense policies.